# PHP: Interfaces and inheritance in a name spaced environment

Tags: php, inheritance, zend-framework2

I am trying to use a interface or child class to work in a situation where I am using class hints on a method argument and keep getting the following warning:

```
$print_r(class_parents($listing));
$propertyTable -> getPhotos($listing);

Array ( [Tools\Object\Property] => Tools\Object\Property ) 

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Tools\Db\PhotoTable::getPhotos() must be an
instance of Tools\Db\Property, instance of Tools\Object\Listing given, called in ... 
and defined in ...
```

This is strange as you can see when tested listing extends property (see below). Why would I get this error?

I have set up a very basic test case and have figured out that type hints should accept a child class or a class that implements the required class where that class is an interface.  However, in a name spaced Zend Framework 2 environment I cannot get this to work.

My code for the various classes looks like this:

```
namespace Tools\Db;

class PhotoTable
{  
   public function getPhotos(Property $propertyObject )
   {  
    //code goes here    
   }
}

 namespace Tools\Object;
 use Tools\Object\PhotoInterface as PhotoInterface;

 class property //implements photoInterface
 {
    public function getUrl(){ code goes here}
    public function getPhotos(){ code goes here}
  }//end class

 use Tools\Object\PhotoInterface as PhotoInterface;

class Listing extends Property implements PhotoInterface
{
//code goes here
}

namespace Tools\Object;

interface PhotoInterface 
{
   public function getUrl();
   public function getPhotos();
}
```

I can get the code above to work if I copy this all into a single file and eliminate the namespaces. Basically:

- if I require property in PhotoTable I can pass Listing as it extends property.
- If I require PhotoInterface I can pass Listing as it implements this interface.

But I get this weird error when I have essentially the same classes in a different files in a name spaced Zend Framework 2 environment.

Is there an extra complication in a name spaced environment I need to take into account of or am I missing something really basic.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue involved the name-spaced files included in the head of the script. Specifically, it appears you need to include not only the class being am passed, but also the specified parent classes or any Interface classes if they are specified in the type hint.

To give an example if my class type hint suggests I need 'property' class, then if I am sending it the 'Listing' object, it seems I need to include property in the header like this:

```
namespace Tools\Object;

use Tools\Object\Property;  //the parent class
use Tools\Object\Listing;  //the child class
```

This eliminates the fatal error, but it seems strange that PHP cannot automatically determine the class automatically.  I assume it is something to do with the complexities of a name spaced environment.